# The storage account does not exist in the current subscription

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

when I use New-AzureDeployment, i get exception like this:

BadRequest : The storage account named xxx does not exist in the current subscription

[image]

and indeed account storage4sp exist in my subscription
[image]

Anything i am wrong ?

Comment: Try to create a "Classic" storage account and use that one please. The storage account you're using is "Resource Manager" storage account.

Comment: Have you also made sure your currently active subscription in PowerShell is correct?

Comment: any updates? do you fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

According to your screenshot, we could find that your .cspkg file is stored in a RM storage account (not classic storage account), which could be the cause of the issue. As Gaurav Mantri said, you could try to store your .cspkg file in a classic storage account, which should resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: I had exactly the same situation and exactly this workaround helped.